# Why can my modal be opened from one tab pane and not from another in my Angular page?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am opening my modal from within my Angular component using the following code:

```
@ViewChild('openMessage', { static: true }) openMessage: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
let el: HTMLElement = this.openMessage.nativeElement; 
el.click()
```

The following hidden link in the page is targeted.

```
<ng-container class="hidden">
    <a #openMessage id="open-message" data-toggle="modal" 
        data-target="#sideModal">CLICK</a>
</ng-container>
```

The links then opens the modal. The problem is when the link is targeted from one tab pane, the modal is opened as expected, from another, it does not open.

From the developer tool, the modal looks like this when it works and is opened, with additional code added by Angular.

```
<div _ngcontent-vre-c7="" aria-labelledby="sideModalTitle" class="modal fade show" 
   id="sideModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1"
    style="display: block;" aria-modal="true">
<div _ngcontent-vre-c7="" class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div _ngcontent-vre-c7="" class="modal-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

The modal code looks like this when it fails to open.

```
<div _ngcontent-vre-c7="" aria-hidden="true" aria-
    labelledby="sideModalTitle" class="modal fade" 
    id="sideModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
<div _ngcontent-vre-c7="" class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div _ngcontent-vre-c7="" class="modal-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular adds various classes to the code when it opens, like class="show" and style="display: block;" but doesn't do the same in the case where the modal is not opened.

Comment: can you create demo code on stackblitz.com ?

Comment: Please upload full code on stackblitz or anyother online utility

Comment: Because of the complexity of the code, it would take quite a while to recreate it on stackblitz but I have included relevant segments of code. They are found in mainpage.html, tabpane.html and tabpane.ts https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng1tgv